# React: How do I use async calls to get a FirebaseToken and then use it in an API call?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a React app that is making calls to an API.  I have a Client component to handle the calls, and the Components can access it like this (this example is in the componentDidMount function of the Home page, where I want to get a list of all this user's items):

```
componentDidMount() {

    let userId= this.context.userId;

    var url = "items/getAllMyItems/" + userId;
    Client.fetchData(url, data => {

      this.setState({items: data});

    });
}
```

The current setup has no security (just for testing purposes) and the Client is defined like this (this is index.js):

```
function fetchData(fetchPath, cb) {
    return fetch(`https://api.url/${fetchPath}`, {accept: "application/json"})
    .then(cb);
}
```

(there are a couple of other functions which check the results etc, but I've left them out for brevity).

Now, my app connects to Firebase for handling authentication.  I have A Firebase component which has 3 files:

firebase.js:

```
import app from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';

const config = {
  apiKey:  /* etc */,
};

class Firebase {
  constructor() {
    app.initializeApp(config);

    this.auth = app.auth();
  }

  // *** Auth API ***

  doSignInWithEmailAndPassword = (email, password) =>
    this.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);

  doSignOut = () => this.auth.signOut();

}

export default Firebase;
```

context.js:

```
import React from 'react';

const FirebaseContext = React.createContext(null);

export const withFirebase = Component => props => (
  <FirebaseContext.Consumer>
    {firebase => <Component {...props} firebase={firebase} />}
  </FirebaseContext.Consumer>
);

export default FirebaseContext;
```

index.js:

```
import FirebaseContext, { withFirebase } from './context';
import Firebase from './firebase';

export default Firebase;

export { FirebaseContext, withFirebase };
```

We're now implementing backend security, and I need to pass the Firebase token to the API when making calls.  I can't figure out how to do it properly.

I know I need to call

```
firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken(true).then(function(idToken) {
  // API call with Authorization: Bearer `idToken`
}).catch(function(error) {
  // Handle error
});
```

so I figured that Client/index.js would need to change to something like:

```
import react from 'react';
import { FirebaseContext } from '../Firebase';

function fetchData(fetchPath, cb) {

  <FirebaseContext.Consumer>
    {firebase => {
      firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken(true)
      .then(function(idToken) {
        // API call with Authorization: Bearer `idToken`
        return fetch(`https://api.url/${fetchPath}`, {accept: "application/json"})
        .then(cb);
      }).catch(function(error) {
        // Handle error
      });
    }}
  </FirebaseContext.Consumer>

}
```

but if I do this I get the error "Expected an assignment or function call but instead saw the expression".  I realize this is because it's expecting me to return a component, but I don't want to do that as there's nothing to return.  I also tried using useContext, and changing fetchData to:

```
const Client = () => {

  const firebase = useContext(FirebaseContext);

  firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken(true)
      .then(function(idToken) {
        // API call with Authorization: Bearer `idToken`
        fetch(`https://api.url/${fetchPath}`, {accept: "application/json"})
        .then(cb);
      }).catch(function(error) {
        // Handle error
  });

}
```

but I got an error about an Invalid Hook Call.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: i read the whole thing above but couldn't figure out in which thing you need help? do you know what is not working. or if you getting token properly?

Comment: I don't understand what I need to put in fetchData... the two things I tried above gave errors.  I don't know whether I'm taking the correct approach or should be doing something totally different. I haven't been able to create code which compiles yet, so I don't know whether I can even get the token properly.

Comment: Is the app wrapped in the `<FirebaseContext.Provider>` somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

The code you have to get the ID token looks fine to me.

How to pass it to the API depends on what that API expects, but since you mention ```Authorization: Bearer `idToken` `` that would typically look like this:

```
fetch(`https://api.url/${fetchPath}`, {
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + idToken
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks.  Still getting "Invalid Hook call" error, though, with or without the header part.  Current code:

import { useContext } from 'react';
import { FirebaseContext } from '../Firebase';

const Client = (fetchPath) => {

  const firebase = useContext(FirebaseContext);
  firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken(true)
      .then(function(idToken) {
        fetch(`https://api.url/${fetchPath}`, {
                  headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + idToken
              }
            });
      })
 
}

Comment: Sorry, the format went wrong there - hopefully it makes sense!

Comment: Hmmm... I'm not sure what that error means. Is there any more information in the error message?